# "String or Binary data would be truncated" on Web Deploy, not in debug mode

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have an ASP.Net app which transfers Excel rows to a SQL Server table and then they get processed by a stored procedure (TableA data gets formatted to TableB, then TableA gets truncated).
Both the app and the stored procedure work fine while debugging directly on the VS environment, but on the web deploy I get the following SQL Exception:

> String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I've already changed the table schema to `nvarchar(200)` on every column, and turned `ansi_warnings` off on the stored procedure but nothing seems to affect the error. Again, this is only on the web deploy which only makes me think that the user permissions on the server side (every user logs in as NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE on SQL).

This is the C# side of the app:

```cs
if (subeArchivo.HasFile)
{
    var fechaYMD = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    var fechaHM = DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmm");

    string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/archivoCargado/" + fechaHM + "_" + fechaYMD + "_" + subeArchivo.FileName));
    subeArchivo.SaveAs(path);

    DataTable dt = ExcelToDataTable(subeArchivo.FileBytes, cbEncabezado.Checked);

    gridDT.DataSource = dt;
    gridDT.DataBind();

    try
    {
        string cadenaConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cadenaSQL"].ConnectionString.ToString();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cadenaConn);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(cadenaConn);

        SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping ID_USU_CAR = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("ID_USU_CAR", "ID_USU_CAR");
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(ID_USU_CAR);
        SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping RUT_DCT = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("RUT_DCT", "RUT_DCT");
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(RUT_DCT);
        SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping TIP_CON = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("TIP_CON", "TIP_CON");
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(TIP_CON);
        SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping ID_CON = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("ID_CON", "ID_CON");
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(ID_CON);
        SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping INI_BEN = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("INI_BEN", "INI_BEN");
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(INI_BEN);
        SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping FIN_BEN = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("FIN_BEN", "FIN_BEN");
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(FIN_BEN);
        SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping MON_CLP = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("MON_CLP", "MON_CLP");
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(MON_CLP);

        bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "TMP_CAR_DCT_BEN";
        bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dt);

        lblCarga.Visible = true;
        lblCarga.Text = "CARGA A SQL COMPLETADA";

        lblSP.Visible = true;
        lblSP.Text = "EJECUTANDO VALIDACIONES";
        cmd.CommandText = "VAL_DCT_BEN_BETA2";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        lblSP.Text = "VALIDACIÓN COMPLETADA";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblConfirma.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
    }

    try
    {
        lblRes.Visible = true;

        connSQL.Open();

        // PROCESO RESUMEN
        SqlCommand selProc = connSQL.CreateCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter adaptadorDatos1 = new SqlDataAdapter(selProc);
        selProc.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CON_PRO_BEN ORDER BY CAST(FEC_CAR AS DATETIME) DESC, HOR_CAR DESC";
        selProc.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        DataTable tablaProcRes = new DataTable();
        adaptadorDatos1.Fill(tablaProcRes);

        gridProcRes.DataSource = tablaProcRes;
        gridProcRes.DataBind();
        gridProcRes.Visible = true;

        connSQL.Close();

        connSQL.Open();

        //  PROCESO DESCRIPTIVO
        SqlCommand selProcDes = connSQL.CreateCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter adaptadorDatos2 = new SqlDataAdapter(selProcDes);
        selProcDes.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM CON_PRO_BEN_DES " +
            "WHERE FEC_CAR = (SELECT MAX(FEC_CAR) FROM CON_PRO_BEN_DES) AND HOR_CAR = (SELECT MAX(HOR_CAR) FROM CON_PRO_BEN_DES) " +
            "ORDER BY HOR_CAR DESC";
        selProcDes.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        DataTable tablaProcResDes = new DataTable();
        adaptadorDatos2.Fill(tablaProcResDes);

        gridProcDes.DataSource = tablaProcResDes;
        gridProcDes.DataBind();
        gridProcDes.Visible = true;

        connSQL.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblResQ.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
else
    lblError.Visible = true;

lblError.Text = "Incidencias en la carga, reintentar.";
```

Comment: Does it fail when transferring data from Excel to the table, or does it fail when running the stored procedure? Why don't you try extending columns to 4000, then it might import and you can see the offending piece of data.

Comment: You can check the max length of the source table and check whether any data is more than the length of the destination table column length.